# "Content Download" extremely slow in Chrome, not in Incognito or other browsers

Tags: google-chrome

I have a logout endpoint that takes several seconds to resolve in Chrome (sometimes up to 30 seconds in production), but only around a hundred milliseconds in every other browsers (Firefox, Safari...) **and** in a new Chrome Incognito window.
Firing the request locally from Chrome against the staging database also runs smoothly.
Checking the *Timing* tab in Network shows that timing for *Request sent* and *Waiting* are normal, but *Content Download* is where most of the time is spent.

I have tried turning off all my extensions (and rebooted Chrome) and tried browsing the Chromium bugs board, to no avail:

- [slow content download](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=862024&can=1&q=content%20download%20slow&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)
- [Network panel shows huge Content Download time for 304 response](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=818683&can=1&q=content%20download%20slow&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)
- [Slow Content Download on Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=829764&can=1&q=content%20download%20slow&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Here's the request:

```
curl "https://XXX.XXX.com/deconnexion" \
     -H 'Authority: XXX.XXX.fr' \
     -H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
     -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
     -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
     -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36' \
     -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' \
     -H 'Referer: https://XXX.XXX.fr/b' \
     -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
     -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,es;q=0.7' \
     -H 'Cookie: __cfduid=XXX; cookie_consent=true;'
```

Which returns an empty response with the following Headers:

```
cache-control: no-cache
cf-ray: 49365c40589abd79-CDG
clear-site-data: "cache", "storage"
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Thu, 03 Jan 2019 15:04:52 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://xxx.cloudflare.com/xxx/xxx/xxx"
location: https://xxx.xxx.fr/xxx/xxx
referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
server: cloudflare
set-cookie: path=/; secure; HttpOnly
status: 302
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-csrf-token: xxxx
x-download-options: noopen
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
x-request-id: xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
x-runtime: 0.017715
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Request in Firefox:

[image: Request in Firefox]

Request in Chrome Incognito:

[image: Request in Chrome Incognito]

Request in Chrome 71 (version *71.0.3578.98*):

[image: Request in Chrome]

UPDATE: Removing the 'Clear-Site-Data' response header solved the issue, but I still have no idea why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only removing the "cache" option for 'Clear-Site-Data' header should fix the problem.

I also have no idea why.

Comment: For anyone else doing research in the delays when issuing the clear-site-data: "cache" header you could read through this thread: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=762417  Doesn't show any solution, only that the Chromium team recognizes the issue.

Comment: I faced the same issue though I have no "clear-site-data" header. I return data from the server in JSON format for JqGrid. It takes 5 seconds for the grid to display a few rows in Google Chrome. Firefox does this in 100ms. Chrome hanging in "Content Download" stage. I have only three headers: Status, Content-Length and Content-type. Then data and exit(0). Maybe I am ending my script improperly?